# Iterative modulo by repeated subtraction?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write an iterative procedure to do modulo arithmetic in scheme *without* using the built in procedures modulo, remainder or /. However I ran into a few problems while trying to write the code, which looks like this so far:

```
(define (mod a b)
    (define (mod-iter a b)
        (cond ((= b 0) 0)
              ((< b 0) (+ old_b new_b))))
    (mod-iter a (- a b)))
```

As you can see,  I ran into the problem of needing to add the original value of b to the current value of b. I am not sure how to go about that. Also, when i left the second conditional's answer to be primitive data (just to make sure the enitre procedure worked), I would get an "unspecified return value" error, and I'm not sure why it happens because the rest of my code loops (or so it seems?) 
    Thank you in advance for any insight to this.

Comment: What is `old_b` and `new_b`?

Comment: Note that this use of an internal define that's just called once is an excellent place to use a “named let”, as illustrated in @ÓscarLópez's [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19084091/1281433).

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `mod-iter` function with arguments `(a b)` you are shadowing the arguments defined in `mod`.  To avoid the shadowing, use different identifiers, as such:

```
(define (mod a b)
  (define (mod-iter ax bx)
    (cond ((= bx 0) 0)
          ((< bx 0) (+ b bx))))
  (mod-iter a (- a b)))
```

Note, this doesn't look like the proper algorithm (there is no recursive call).  How do you handle the common case of `(> bx 0)`?  You'll need something like:

```
(define (mod a b)
  (define (mod-iter ax bx)
    (cond ((= bx 0) 0)
          ((< bx 0) (+ b bx))
          ((> bx 0) ...)))        ;; <- something here with mod-iter?
  (mod-iter a (- a b)))
```

Comment: Can use `else` since if it's not equal or lower it has to be higher.

Comment: The call to `mod-iter` at the end of `mod` isn't right;  it doesn't have access to any `ax` or `bx`.  Those should be `a` and `b`, no?

Comment: I realize I can use `else` but this enumerates all the numeric possibilities explicitly.  Thanks.

Comment: Fixed, bad rewrite of the original.

Comment: `ax` and `bx` are still used in the call to `mod-iter` in the first definition of `mod`, but should be `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't want to capture a variable name, use different variable names in the inner function. Second i think the arguments are wrong compared to the built-in version. (modulo 5 6) is 5 and (modulo 6 5) is 1. Anyways here is a variation in logrirthmic time. That based on generating a list of powers of b (2 4 8 16 32 ...) is b is 2, all the way up to just under the value of a. Then by opportunistically subtracting these reversed values. That way problems like (mod (expt 267 34)  85) return an answer very quickly. (a few hundred primitive function calls vs several million)

```
(define (mod a-in b-in)
 (letrec ((a (abs a-in))
           (sign (if (< 0 b-in) - +))
           (b (abs b-in))
       (powers-list-calc 
        (lambda (next-exponent) 
          (cond ((> b a) '())
            ((=  next-exponent 0) 
            (error "Number 0 passed as the second argument to mod 
                is not in the correct range"))
                   (else (cons next-exponent (powers-list (* b next-exponent))))))))
    (let ((powers-list (reverse (powers-list-calc b))))
      (sign
    (let loop ((a a) (powers-L powers-list))
          (cond ((null? powers-L) a)
                ((> a (car powers-L))
            (loop (- a (car powers-L)) powers-L))
                (else (loop a (cdr powers-L)))))))))
```